# Strip Html string from behinde for specific amount of <br> tags

Tags: c#, html, regex

If i have a html string like :

```
    <strong>
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
<table></table>
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
    <br />\r\n
    </strong>\r\n
    </span>\r\n
```

is it possible to strip html so that i only have 1 `<br>` at the end of html, so people  wont be able to create 40 new lines at the end?

**Solution would look like :**

```
  <strong>
        <br />\r\n
        <br />\r\n
    <table></table>
        <br />\r\n
        </strong>\r\n
        </span>\r\n
```

Comment: By your tags are you wanting to parse html with a regex? Uh oh!

Comment: its telerik radeditor im using, updated my answer

Comment: Parsing html with regex is a fantastic idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Also, putting a `<table>` in a `<strong>` is not good. Most browsers don't care that you're breaking the rules, but what if you  stumble into a browser that does care? Especially as you're trying to output XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what context you're asking your question in, but you could just use jQuery on the page itself using [the next adjacent selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-adjacent-Selector/)  like the following:

```
$("br+br").remove();
```

[Here is an example of it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/fpWGG/2/)

If you want to *just* remove the break tags that come after your table, simply alter your jQuery statement to look something like this:

```
$("table").nextAll("br+br").remove();
```

[Here is an example of this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/fpWGG/6/)

And here are instructions for [including jQuery in your page](http://think2loud.com/576-jquery-101-adding-jquery-to-your-website/).

Answer (score 0):

If you can, take a look at [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It can help you here.

This a test code that I wrote:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.Load(@"E:\Libs\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.0\htmlstring.html");

    var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//br").Skip(3);

    foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.PreviousSibling.Remove();

        node.Remove();
    }

    var output = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

    htmlDoc.Save(@"E:\Libs\HtmlAgilityPack.1.4.0\htmlstring-changed.html");
}
```